# vue3 / quasar tooltip delay: vscode complaining about datatype

Tags: html, typescript, types, vuejs3, quasar

I am configuring a simple [tooltip](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tooltip/) using quasar on a vue3 website.
When I add a delay (I tried many variations, incl. delay=500,  delay="500" or :delay=500), the mouse hover over the word "delay" in vscode keeps complaining about the number being a string..

Any ideas?

**The "code":**

```
<q-tooltip delay="500" >abcd</q-tooltip>
```

**The Error:** *(visible when hovering with the mouse in vscode over the word "delay")*

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)

index.d.ts(13221, 3): The expected type comes from property 'delay' which is declared here on type 'VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & QTooltipProps & Record<string, unknown>'

(property) QTooltipProps.delay?: number | undefined
Configure Tooltip to appear with delay
```

Answer (score 1):

It was simple...

```
:delay="500"
```